# Having issues Installing postgresql with homebrew

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, homebrew

Basically i did

```
brew install postgresql
```

and this is the error i get,

```
==> Downloading   http://ftp9.us.postgresql.org/pub/mirrors/postgresql/source/v9.1.1/postgresql-9.1.1.tar.bz2

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403
Error: Download failed: http://ftp9.us.postgresql.org/pub/mirrors/postgresql/source/v9.1.1/postgresql-9.1.1.tar.bz2
```

I thought installing postgresql using brew is easy, anyone facing the same problem ?

Comment: PostgreSQL is typically installed on Mac OS X systems via EnterpriseDB's One-click binary installers, which are officially supported, or via MacPorts. I haven't seen mention of `brew` or `homebrew` on the PostgreSQL mailing lists before now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears the URL has changed but the formula hasn't been updated yet.

> The formula has now been updated. Instead of manually fixing
>   the recipe as the rest of this answer suggests, just update your
>   homebrew recipes via `brew update` and try the install again.

You can edit the formula yourself with the `brew edit postgresql` command.  Change the `url` to `http://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v9.1.1/postgresql-9.1.1.tar.bz2` and try to install again.

Comment: thanks dude, this is helpful. Hopefully it helps others facing this problem as well.

Comment: The base URLs have changed - mainly because of just this type of problem. Hardcoding something against "ftp9.us.postgresql.org" was wrong in the first place, but lots of people did that. Unfortunately, that machine is outside the control of the PostgreSQL community, so there's no control of when things like this happen.

Comment: Yeah, it's a hassle but easily remedied by going to the postgresql.org site and finding the ftp link for the source download.

Comment: It's worth noting that editing the url manually in the file may disrupt a 'brew update'. Since 'brew update' is essentially a git update, modified files cause problems because git stops the update to ask you to commit your changes. Currently there is no 'force' behavior. For more details, see this link - https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/14224

Answer (score 2):

MD5 for http://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v9.1.1/postgresql-9.1.1.tar.bz2 is 061a9f17323117c9358ed60f33ecff78

Comment: Mike, I added your md5 answer as an edit to the answer above, since it's crucial for the solution.